# How to import XML data on ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-webpages

Suppose I have a XML file where I put some data like this:

```
<data>
    <value1>01</value1>
    <value2>02</value2>
    <value3>03</value3>
</data>
```

Now I need to import this data on my ASP.NET (C#) web page as integer like below:

```
@{
    int V1= (/xmlDataImportCode/value1);
    int V2= (/xmlDataImportCode/value2);
    int V3= (/xmlDataImportCode/value3);
}
```

I tried following code but it show me error message:

```
@{
    XDocument X = XDocument.Load("~/xml/INFO.xml");
    var value1= X.Element("data").Element("value1");
}
```

The error is

> Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'XDocument'
>   could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: nothing at all, actually I have no idea to do it

Comment: Ah, so you want us to write your code for you? A simple web search of "c# extract data from XML" got me lots of good hits.

Comment: you dont have to give me full solution, just give me some hint if you can

Comment: Sorry, not even going to do that until you clean your question up. For example, you posted some code you tried and said you got an error message. But you didn't say what the error was or where it occurred. You also haven't stated whether you're using Web Forms, MVC, or Web Pages. Please do that and I'll be more inclined to provide hints.

Comment: `XDocument` is perfectly usable in ASP.NET. Clean your question up according to my last comment, and I'll give you more hints.

Comment: I am using Web Pages and the error message is "Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'XDocument' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: I have cleaned up your question based on the information you just told me. Please look at it and realize that's how you should have done it in the first place. As for your error, that's a common and easy one to solve. It's basically saying you need to add the namespace. I'm not super familiar with Web Pages, so I'm not sure how you'd add it via configuration. The namespace is `System.Xml.Linq`. Also note you'll need to pass an absolute path to `XDocument.Load()`.

Comment: You need to reference System.Xml.Linq, and you need to add the namespace to whatever that thingy is in web.config.  Or just type System.Xml.Linq.XDocument everywhere.

Comment: I added ``System.XML.Linq`` like this `@using System.XML.Linq{....}` and solved namespace error but the  variable ``value1`` do not work. I called this variable in a `<p></p>` tag but it show me this error message "Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'value1' does not exist in the current context"